# Record data in excel for each iteration

Tags: excel, vba

I am in dire need of solution to my long pending problem as below.

Based on editable selections which could be done in few cells set in my worksheet, cells C28 to F28 constantly calculates answers based on selections. Everytime I make a change to editable selection, values in these cells (C28 to F28) changes. I want to keep the record of last nos. in these cells just before everytime the last change is made. I need to then show relation (in %) between previous nos. and nos. with current change which is easy.

I preferably don't want to use VBA to do this since I have never used it before and thus not comfortable. But if VBA is the only solution to this, then be it!
If this works out, this worksheet needs to be sent to many users so, whatever is the trick - needs to work for any user once the file is mailed.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is no VBA answer:

Before you do the changes you need to copy your range (C28 toF28) and paste special only with values in some part of your sheets.

And you will have records of all your calculation.

**EDIT WITH VBA SOLUTION:**

If i understood correctly you have issuse like on picture:

[image: That will do code under this picture]

**1. You need to go in to Visual Basic editor (Alt+F11) (you will get something like this):**

[image]

**2. Than you need double click name of sheet you whant to execute this code**

[image]

**3. Copy this code and paste it into right window, like this:**

[image]

**CODE:**

```
Dim valueOfC28 As Long
Dim valueOfD28 As Long
Dim valueOfE28 As Long
Dim valueOfF28 As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.AddressLocal = Range("C23").AddressLocal Then
    Range("C29").Value = valueOfC28
End If
If Target.AddressLocal = Range("D23").AddressLocal Then
    Range("D29").Value = valueOfD28
End If
If Target.AddressLocal = Range("E23").AddressLocal Then
    Range("E29").Value = valueOfE28
End If
If Target.AddressLocal = Range("F23").AddressLocal Then
    Range("F29").Value = valueOfF28
End If


End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.AddressLocal = Range("C23").AddressLocal Then
    valueOfC28 = Range("C28").Value
End If
If Target.AddressLocal = Range("D23").AddressLocal Then
    valueOfD28 = Range("D28").Value
End If
If Target.AddressLocal = Range("E23").AddressLocal Then
    valueOfE28 = Range("E28").Value
End If
If Target.AddressLocal = Range("F23").AddressLocal Then
    valueOfF28 = Range("F28").Value
End If
End Sub
```

I hope it will help!

**EDIT FOR COLLECTION YOU NEED:**

replace this code with existing code:

```
Dim valueOfC28 As Long
Dim valueOfD28 As Long
Dim valueOfE28 As Long
Dim valueOfF28 As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim inc As Integer
Dim flag As Boolean
Dim OLDvalueOfC29 As Long
Dim OLDvalueOfD29 As Long
Dim OLDvalueOfE29 As Long
Dim OLDvalueOfF29 As Long
Dim SheetName As String
flag = False
OLDvalueOfC29 = Range("C29").Value
OLDvalueOfD29 = Range("D29").Value
OLDvalueOfE29 = Range("E29").Value
OLDvalueOfF29 = Range("F29").Value
If Target.AddressLocal = Range("C23").AddressLocal Then
    flag = True
    Range("C29").Value = valueOfC28
End If
If Target.AddressLocal = Range("D23").AddressLocal Then
    flag = True
    Range("D29").Value = valueOfD28
End If
If Target.AddressLocal = Range("E23").AddressLocal Then
    flag = True
    Range("E29").Value = valueOfE28
End If
If Target.AddressLocal = Range("F23").AddressLocal Then
    flag = True
    Range("F29").Value = valueOfF28
End If
If Target.AddressLocal = Range("C23:F23").AddressLocal Then
    flag = True
    Range("C29").Value = valueOfC28
    Range("D29").Value = valueOfD28
    Range("E29").Value = valueOfE28
    Range("F29").Value = valueOfF28
End If

If flag = True Then
    inc = 1
    Do While Range("K" & inc).Value <> ""
        inc = inc + 1
    Loop
    Range("K" & inc) = OLDvalueOfC29
    Range("L" & inc) = OLDvalueOfD29
    Range("M" & inc) = OLDvalueOfE29
    Range("N" & inc) = OLDvalueOfF29
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.AddressLocal = Range("C23").AddressLocal Then
    valueOfC28 = Range("C28").Value
End If
If Target.AddressLocal = Range("D23").AddressLocal Then
    valueOfD28 = Range("D28").Value
End If
If Target.AddressLocal = Range("E23").AddressLocal Then
    valueOfE28 = Range("E28").Value
End If
If Target.AddressLocal = Range("F23").AddressLocal Then
    valueOfF28 = Range("F28").Value
End If

If Target.AddressLocal = Range("C23:F23").AddressLocal Then
    valueOfC28 = Range("C28").Value
    valueOfD28 = Range("D28").Value
    valueOfE28 = Range("E28").Value
    valueOfF28 = Range("F28").Value
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thats unfortunately not what I am looking at. Because the whole idea of automation and giving user realtime feedback of his selection is lost. User will not be willing to do this copy paste every time he sees change in the nos. and want to see a percentage difference against previous nos.... I believed there should have been a way out either through VBA or i dont know, may be even pivot tables. Any further help will be appreciated

Comment: Thank you so much for drafting down full code for me and way to implement it, this is really appreciated. I tried to exactly replicate the operation way you said, however, my cells from C29 to F29 automatically got assigned with no. 0, i believe due to the code. After that, whatever changes I made to cells C23:F23, it retained 0 in C29:F29. Would you be able to help further to find out the error.

Comment: Also, how does the code work normally? Will it automatically update the values in C29:F29 every time there is a change in C23:F23, thats what should really be the case! And I also hope the undo function works normally with the code.

Comment: @Ranup Rathi, for your first question. Do you link C23->C28, D23->D28....F23->F28 for exampample write in C28 cell "=C23"? If you do not you will get 0 in cells. And for your second part of your second question my answer is undo does not work for any macro command. If you have issuse like that you need to collect every changes and write in predefined rows to can access them later.